# Disconnect fixture's connection at the end of test module in PyTest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, python-3.9

I have a test module running with PyTest.

A fixture establishes a connection to a Redis client and flushes all at the end of each test:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def redis_conn():
    conn = redis.Redis(decode_responses=True, **config.redis_test_credentials)
    yield conn
    conn.flushall()
```

In addition to that, I need to call this *after* all tests from the module have finished:

```
conn.connection.disconnect()
```

Some things I've thought about and why they didn't work:

- I can't use a `pytest.fixture(scope='module')` here because then `conn.flushall()` would run only after this module's tests are all done
- I also don't see how to use `pytest_unconfigure()` because I don't see a way to access the `conn` object from there.

How to make sure that `conn.connection.disconnect()` is executed after all tests from the module are done, while keeping `conn.flushall()` after each test?

-- EDIT

There is one additional constraint that I omitted, which is that the `redis_conn` fixture is used into a function-level mock:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_redis_conn(mocker, redis_conn):
    """ Mock Redis connection """
    mocker.patch("mymodule.api.redis_conn", new=redis_conn)
```

This mocked `mymodule.api.redis_conn` should effectively call `flushall()` after each test is run, which prevents me from scoping this mock to the `module` level.

Comment: how about using `scope='session'` ?

Comment: How about to split fixture and use wide scope (module or session) to open and close connection and `scope=function` to flush data?

Comment: @Macintosh_89 wouldn't the flush be done at the end of the entire session, then?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs how would you split such a fixture?

Comment: Straightforward :) you could inject fixtures into fixtures through parameters, exactly like in tests

Comment: @NobbyNobbs yes but when I do this, then an error happens: `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'event_loop' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories`

Comment: @jivan sorry i misread the question. out of curiosity why would you want to run it again. Will it not flush all the data after last test is run ?

Comment: @Macintosh_89 because each test persists and reads its own bunch of data, hence the need to flush everything after each test, so that the next test starts from a clear slate

Comment: I would suggest then you have a `setup_method` and `teardown_method` function which flushes data for each test and `setup_class` and `teardown_class` which will create and teardown redis connection

Comment: You did something wrong with fixtures scopes. Injecting module-scoped fixture into function-scoped, but it must be vice versa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement fixtures which depends on others fixtures.

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import pytest

class RedisConn:
    """just stub for example"""
    def flush(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

connection = RedisConn()

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def conn():
    conn = MagicMock()  # here you open connection to testing Redis instance
    print("open connection")
    yield conn
    print("close connection")

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def flush(conn, mocker):
    mocker.patch(f"{__name__}.connection", new=conn)
    print("do nothing")
    yield
    print(f"flush {connection}")
    connection.flush()

def test_main_1(flush):
    assert isinstance(connection, MagicMock)
    print("test 1 body")

def test_main_2(flush):
    assert isinstance(connection, MagicMock)
    print("test 2 body")

def test_main_3():
    assert not isinstance(connection, MagicMock)
    assert isinstance(connection, RedisConn)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__, "-s"])
```

prints

```
open connection
do nothing
test 1 body
.
flush <MagicMock id='139710977083536'>
do nothing
test 2 body
.
flush <MagicMock id='139710977083536'>
.
close connection
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't see it that way! Yes I see how that would work — however in the question I omitted that I'm also using `conn` in a mock and pytest is not happy about me mocking on `function` scope with a fixture on `module` scope — I'm editing the question to reflect this

Comment: Note that if I don't use `conn` within a mock, then all works fine according to your example (except I'm not mocking what I need to mock, therefore the tests fail).

Comment: please check, I've updated the code snippet

Comment: code snippet is perfectly clear and makes sense... somehow my real-world case is not behaving so well, still got a ScopeMismatch error. Maybe I'm overlooking something or this has to do with the real case using an asyncio connection, therefore using coroutines everywhere.

Comment: Maybe it's pytest-asyncio [issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/68)

Comment: Probably. A bit too tired to go down this rabbit hole right now, but I accept your answer because it obviously solves the question as it was asked.